# magento not working after rename Databse for testing

Tags: database, magento, runtime-error, rename

I have a shared server with so many magento sites on there and want to check which database is for which site.

I have check the database name in confi.xml and rename that
database to something else for testing

But when i rename it to original it didn't work

**Please suggest whats the issue**

thanks

Comment: we set databse name in app/etc/local.xml not some config.xml

Comment: Did you clear cache in magentoroot/var/cache?